# How to stretch all rectangles in SVG so they take all width

Tags: html, css, svg, rectangles

I have this SVG:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="40" viewBox="0 0 371 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="57"  y="1" width="45" height="15" fill="#e1d6f2"/>
    <rect x="103" y="1" width="45" height="15" fill="#c1b0e2"/>
    <rect x="149" y="1" width="45" height="15" fill="#9b80ce"/>
    <rect x="195" y="1" width="45" height="15" fill="#6d4cbf"/>
    <rect x="241" y="1" width="45" height="15" fill="#4d2c7a"/>
    <text x="57" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">0</text>
    <text x="102" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">20</text>
    <text x="147" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">40</text>
    <text x="192" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">60</text>
    <text x="237" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">80</text>
    <text x="290" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">100%</text>
</svg>
```

Currently SVG takes the width of the parent container but rectangles stay the same size. I want them take all width and scale with window resize. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to add the width and the `x` values as percentages.

An example would be the following :

```html
<svg width="100%" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="25%" height="15" fill="#e1d6f2" />
  <rect width="25%" height="15" fill="#c1b0e2" x="20%" />
  <rect width="25%" height="15" fill="#9b80ce" x="40%"/>
  <rect width="25%" height="15" fill="#6d4cbf" x="60%"/>
  <rect width="25%" height="15" fill="#4d2c7a" x="80%"/>
  <text x="3%" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">0</text>
  <text x="20%" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">20</text>
  <text x="40%" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">40</text>
  <text x="60%" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">60</text>
  <text x="80%" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">80</text>
  <text x="96%" y="38" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000">100%</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I wanted! The only thing more: do you think it is still possible to align 0% and 100% on the edges of this scale? Like I had it in the example.

Comment: @OlgaB if you do that then they'll appear outside of the window as the rectangles are taking 100% of the width : https://jsfiddle.net/wf31ky7t/

Comment: You could try to keep reducing till you get the result you need (https://jsfiddle.net/x98vn12g/) but you asked in the OP for full width so that's what I did :-) Do you need any code explanation?

Comment: yes, I was going to suggest that I can keep reducing this. :) Thank you again!